# PowerShell MethodNotFound,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.ForeachObjectCommand

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to do the following:

`Get-ChildItem [DIR] -include [FILETYPE] -recurse | foreach ($_) { Remove-Item $_.fullname -WhatIf }`

Would like to run in a function:

`Function funcNameHere() {
        Get-ChildItem [DIR] -include [FILETYPE] -recurse | foreach ($_) { Remove-Item $_.fullname -WhatIf }
}`

If I run this piece of code in the main portion of the script, it runs without any problems, however if I attempt to place into a function, then it returns the error:

`foreach : Input name "1" cannot be resolved to a method.
At [script]:## char: ##
foreach to the last brace is underlined in tildes.
+ CategoryInfo Invalid Argument ([script]:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: MethodNotFound,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.ForeachObjectCommand`

I am unable to turn anything up on google for this error, any help would be appreciated.

Yes, [DIR] and [FILETYPE] are defined normally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the `foreach` _statement_ with the `ForEach-Object` _cmdlet_ (the latter is aliased to `foreach`, which can cause confusion). Do not use `($_)` with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet - the script block `{ ... }` you pass to it will have `$_` automatically defined. Also, consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, working just fine now.